# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor

Tags: java, web-services, maven, servlets

I think I messed something up with my configuration of my jax-rs webservice, but I don't know what causes this error. I am using Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) and Maven.

EDIT: I use Tomcat 7.0 and JDK 1.8_65

---

```
SEVERE: Servlet /webservice threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.vcivf</groupId>
<artifactId>vcivf-webservice</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>webservice</name>

<build>
    <finalName>webservice</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

I tried to resolve this by trying other solutions here on stackoverflow, but either I did not understand what I shall do or the solution did not work. The strange thing is also, that there are many solutions out there for the same problem. What do you think: How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is which server used for running this project? Use tomcat 7 and try following dependecies.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I added the depencies, now I get the following errors:
`SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource.wadlContext
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages`
and `SEVERE: Servlet /webservice threw load() exception
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException`

Comment: did you use tomcat instead of glassfish?

Comment: I use Tomcat 7 in Eclipse, but my pom.XML has `<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>`. Shall I change this to `<groupId>org.tomcat.jersey</groupId>`?